# Ajax not seeing textarea value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, django

I have a textarea input on my page that I want to post to the server using AJAX. The AJAX call is good, however, it will not see the value that's inside the textarea.

My HTML:

```
<div class="promptBody">
    <div id="promptText" onclick="replaceWithInput(this)">
        <p class="promptBody"><div id="prompty">{{prompt.prompt|linebreaks}}</div></p>
    </div>
    <form id="promptUpdateForm">
        <div id="promptInput">
            <p><textarea class="input" cols="40" id="id_prompt" name="prompt" placeholder="Prompt" rows="10"></textarea></p>
            <p><input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Edit Prompt" /></p>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on('submit', '#promptUpdateForm', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/apps/litprompt/a/{{prompt.id}}/update/',
                data: {
                    'prompt': $('#id_prompt').val(),
                    csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val(),
                },
                success: function(json) {
                    $('#promptText').html(json.prompt_data);
                    var promptText = document.getElementById('promptText');
                    var promptInput = document.getElementById('promptInput');
                    promptText.style.display = 'block';
                    promptInput.style.display = 'none';
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

If I change my ajax code in data to 'prompt': 'blah', it works just fine. But every time I post with 'prompt': $('#id_prompt').val(), it is a null value.

Comment: You forgot to close the textarea, they aren't self closing, and requires a `</textarea>` closing tag

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I forgot the </textarea> when I was reformatting the code for the question, but it is in the actual code and it still isn't working. I reformatted the question to correct that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `textarea` HTML element is not self-closing. It has to be closed by `</textarea>`.

See as follows:

```
<div class="promptBody">
    <div id="promptText" onclick="replaceWithInput(this)">
        <p class="promptBody"><div id="prompty">{{prompt.prompt|linebreaks}}</div></p>
    </div>
    <form id="promptUpdateForm">
        <div id="promptInput">
            <p><textarea class="input" cols="40" id="id_prompt" name="prompt" placeholder="Prompt" rows="10"></textarea></p>
            <p><input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Edit Prompt" /></p>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry, i forgot the </textarea> when I was rewriting the code for the question. I do have a </textarea> in there and it is still broken. I updated the question to correct this.

Comment: In that case, are you sure you don't have `id_prompt` defined elsewhere? Because a simple mock up on https://jsfiddle.net/sbra8y8t/ seems to be working.

Comment: Ah! I had a new prompt form on the same page that was generating another textarea with the same ID. That did it. Thanks!